# How to get "Failed to fetch" reason?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Some of my users are encountering a "Failed to fetch" issue on certain `fetch` requests. I'm trying to figure out why. It's fetching from the same domain, so it shouldn't be a CORS issue.

Is there any way I can get more info? e.g. in Chrome, when I intentionally block the URL, it tells me `blocked:devtools`. Can I get similar info out of the error object in a `.catch` block? e.g. bad headers, CORS rejection, lost internet, whatever?

To be clear, I want to get this info programmatically. My users are experiencing this issue, not me. I'll send the data to my error catcher to debug further.

[image]

---

`PerformanceObserver` does not seem to report on requests that have failed:

```js
(async () => {
    const o = new PerformanceObserver((list, observer) => {
        console.log('observation!')
        console.log(list.getEntries())
    })
    o.observe({entryTypes:['resource']})
    fetch('/fail').then(console.info,console.error)
    o.disconnect()
})()
```

Comment: You can determine if the fetch made its way through the pipes by using either a ServiceWorker, or a PerformanceObserver (type "resource"). This will allow you to find out if that got rejected because of an actual TypeError (e.g invalid URL), or because of a network issue.

Comment: @Kaiido Are you sure `PerformanceObserver` reports on resources that have failed? I added a snippet to my question, I can't get it to print anything upon failure (neither 404 or blocked network request). Will try looking into a ServiceWorker some more.

Comment: 404 should not reject. CORS should be caught yes. However I just noticed a weird behavior in FF where they do report `https://www.google.com` but not `https://google.com`. Not sure what kind of issue this is. In Chrome all are reported: https://jsfiddle.net/pmeaf47b/ (beware this is really just  a proof of concept, it's utterly hackish).

Comment: You will not be able to know exactly what the error is, you just know the request failed